# I can't insert value in my acces database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

This my code in VB.NET.

My try catch says there is a syntax error in the instruction `INSERT INTO`. I don't know what happened to my INSERT. I searched for the error for over an hour... I'm not an expert in VB.NET, I'm better in C#, but I need to do this  anyway in VB...

Thanks for helping me!!

```
Sub InsertRecord()
Dim conClasf As OleDbConnection
Dim cmdClasf As New OleDbCommand
Dim strClasf As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim intRowsAff As Integer

 lblErrMsg.Text = ""
 lblRecsAff.Text = ""
  strClasf = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
         "Data Source=" & _
         server.mappath("BecsEtMuseaux.mdb") & ";"
 conClasf = New OleDbConnection(strClasf)
 conClasf.Open

Randomize
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO client (" & _
        "UserName, " & _
        "Prenom, " & _
        "Nom, " & _
        "password, " & _
        "mail, " & _
        "Addresse, " & _
        "Ville, " & _
        "PostalCode, " & _
        "Province, " & _
        "Pays, " & _
        "AnimalGenre, " & _
        "NomAnimal, " & _
        "Race, " & _
") VALUES ('" & _
        Replace(txtUserName.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', '" & _
        Replace(txtPrénom.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', '" & _
        Replace(txtNom.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', '" & _
        Replace(txtPass.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', '" & _
        Replace(txtMail.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', " & _
        Replace(txtAdresse.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', " & _
         Replace(txtVille.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', " & _
        Replace(txtPostal.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', " & _
         Replace(txtProvince.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', " & _
         Replace(txtPays.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', " & _
         Replace(rblAnimal.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', " & _
        Replace(txtAnimal.Text, "'", "''") & _
        "', " & _
         Replace(txtRace.Text, "'", "''")

      cmdClasf = New OleDbCommand(strSQL, conClasf)
      Try
      intRowsAff = cmdClasf.ExecuteNonQuery()
      Catch ex As Exception
      lblErrMsg.Text = ex.Message    
      End Try
      lblRecsAff.Text = intRowsAff & " record(s) inserted"
      conClasf.Close
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this cause you an error.

```
       "Race, " & _ //Race**,** try to remove ,
")
```

Much better if you try this:

You can use Parameters to avoid sqlinjection.

```
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO client (UserName,Prenom,Nom,password,mail,Addresse,Ville,PostalCode,Province,Pays,AnimalGenre,NomAnimal,Race) VALUES (@UserName,@Prenom,@Nom,@password,@mail,@Addresse,@Ville,@PostalCode,@Province,@Pays,@AnimalGenre,@NomAnimal,@Race)"

  cmdClasf.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = txtUserName.Text
 //DO OTHER STUFF UNITL @Race
```

See also:

[Parameter Queries in ASP.NET with MS Access](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/26/Parameter-Queries-in-ASP.NET-with-MS-Access)

[Configuring Parameters and Parameter Data Types (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx)

[Use Parameters in your sql command](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VB/Database-ADO.net/UseParametersinyoursqlcommand.htm)

Hope this help.

Regards

Comment: This is not SqlDbType this is access  are you sure this will work whit

Comment: Its VB. Try it. Parameter Queries in ASP.NET with MS Access

Comment: I try your tips whit parameter and I still get an error whit  the instruction INSERT INTO

Answer (score 2):

Escape the Password field. It is reserved word of [Access Engine.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/learn-about-access-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010341461.aspx).

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO client (UserName,Prenom,Nom,[password],mail,
          Addresse,Ville,PostalCode,Province,Pays,AnimalGenre,NomAnimal,Race)
          VALUES 
          (@UserName,@Prenom,@Nom,@password,@mail,
            @Addresse,@Ville,@PostalCode,@Province,@Pays,
             @AnimalGenre,@NomAnimal,@Race)"
```